# Android app hanging until Force close

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am making an application using navigation slider menu. I haven't used it much before so I can't figure out the problems. I used the navigation menu code given at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html. But I am not using the fragments. Instead I am using individual activities. Here is the Main activity.

```
package com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.menu.Bug;
import com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.menu.Details;
import com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.menu.FeedBack;
import com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.option.Contribute;
import com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.option.Event;
import com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.option.Societies;
import com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.option.ThaparLogs;
import com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.option.TimeTable;

public class Main extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mActivityTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mActivityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navDrawer);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mActivityTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        Intent i;
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.details:
                i=new Intent(this,Details.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            case R.id.Feedback:
                i=new Intent(this,FeedBack.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            case R.id.Bug:
                i = new Intent(this,Bug.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing option
        Intent i = null;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                i= new Intent(this,Main.class);
                break;
            case 1:
                i=new Intent(this, Societies.class);
                break;
            case 2:
                i=new Intent(this, Event.class);
                break;
            case 3:
                i=new Intent(this, ThaparLogs.class);
                break;
            case 4:
                i=new Intent(this, TimeTable.class);
                break;
            case 5:
                i=new Intent(this, Contribute.class);
                break;
            default:

                break;
        }

        startActivity(i);

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mActivityTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

When I run the application it goes on a streak of giving out the following error and in between showing warnings that the main thread is doing too much work.

```
02-07 07:19:17.983  32104-32104/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-07 07:19:18.401  32104-32104/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
02-07 07:19:18.922  32104-32114/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.581ms
02-07 07:19:20.686    1921-1921/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-07 07:19:21.312    1921-1931/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 74.164ms
02-07 07:19:21.759    1921-1931/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 20.377ms
02-07 07:19:23.746    1921-1931/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.388ms
02-07 07:19:24.246    1921-1931/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.694ms
02-07 07:19:24.892    1921-1931/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 153.868ms
02-07 07:19:25.276    1921-1931/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 36.983ms
02-07 07:19:25.650    1921-2050/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
02-07 07:19:25.780    1921-1921/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
02-07 07:19:26.418    1921-1921/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-07 07:19:26.695    1921-2050/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
    Build Date: 10/28/14 Tue
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/l_LNX.LA.3.6
    Local Patches: NONE

02-07 07:19:26.957    1921-2050/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-07 07:19:27.245    1921-1931/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.595ms
02-07 07:19:28.289    1921-1921/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 109 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-07 07:19:29.753    1921-1931/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.637ms
02-07 07:19:30.705    1921-1921/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 136 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-07 07:19:33.275    2132-2141/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 123.303ms
02-07 07:19:33.946    2132-2249/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
02-07 07:19:33.998    2132-2132/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
02-07 07:19:34.194    2132-2249/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
    Build Date: 10/28/14 Tue
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/l_LNX.LA.3.6
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107 + cb93e16 + f50fe49 + d7c18e6 + 5b9a565 + 0f3a25d + 607156e + 75511aa + e4d16c0 + 686f3eb + 211a271 + dd281ee +  NOTHING
02-07 07:19:34.205    2132-2249/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-07 07:19:34.318    2132-2249/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-07 07:19:38.892    2132-2132/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
02-07 07:19:39.319    2132-2132/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
02-07 07:19:42.248    2132-2132/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
02-07 07:19:55.051    2132-2249/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
    Build Date: 10/28/14 Tue
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/l_LNX.LA.3.6
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107 + cb93e16 + f50fe49 + d7c18e6 + 5b9a565 + 0f3a25d + 607156e + 75511aa + e4d16c0 + 686f3eb + 211a271 + dd281ee +  NOTHING
02-07 07:19:55.052    2132-2249/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-07 07:19:58.168    2132-2155/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 216(9KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 17MB/18MB, paused 9.187ms total 26.860ms
02-07 07:19:58.261    2132-2141/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 83.786ms
02-07 07:19:58.313    2132-2155/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8585(411KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 17MB/29MB, paused 893us total 136.319ms
02-07 07:20:12.712    2132-2132/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
02-07 07:20:18.494    2132-2157/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 28110(1992KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(36KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.265ms total 165.625ms
02-07 07:20:27.943    2132-2132/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-07 07:20:31.515    3199-3229/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
02-07 07:20:31.538    3199-3199/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
02-07 07:20:31.650    3199-3229/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
    Build Date: 10/28/14 Tue
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/l_LNX.LA.3.6
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107 + cb93e16 + f50fe49 + d7c18e6 + 5b9a565 + 0f3a25d + 607156e + 75511aa + e4d16c0 + 686f3eb + 211a271 + dd281ee +  NOTHING
02-07 07:20:31.656    3199-3229/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-07 07:20:31.761    3199-3229/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-07 07:20:32.572    3199-3199/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-07 07:20:36.030    3199-3199/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
02-07 07:20:36.860    3199-3199/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
02-07 07:20:41.139    3199-3209/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 83.522ms
02-07 07:20:41.509    3199-3199/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 159 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-07 07:20:41.561    3199-3209/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.975ms
02-07 07:20:42.061    3199-3209/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.818ms
02-07 07:20:43.062    3199-3209/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.856ms
02-07 07:20:44.303    3199-3199/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 132 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-07 07:20:45.745    3484-3494/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 13.165ms
02-07 07:20:46.118    3484-3532/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
02-07 07:20:46.164    3484-3484/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
02-07 07:20:46.248    3484-3494/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 16.288ms
02-07 07:20:46.451    3484-3532/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
    Build Date: 10/28/14 Tue
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/l_LNX.LA.3.6
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107 + cb93e16 + f50fe49 + d7c18e6 + 5b9a565 + 0f3a25d + 607156e + 75511aa + e4d16c0 + 686f3eb + 211a271 + dd281ee +  NOTHING
02-07 07:20:46.464    3484-3532/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-07 07:20:46.653    3484-3532/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-07 07:20:48.219    3484-3484/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress.Main}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
02-07 07:20:49.153    3484-3484/com.example.thereaper.thaparexpress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onCreate(..) method you are calling at the end:

```
selectItem(0);
```

And in your selectItem(int position) method you are starting the Main activity:

```
case 0:
     i= new Intent(this,Main.class)
     break;
.....
startActivity(i);
```

So somehow you are creating a infinite loop, thats why your phone complains about much work.

```
Choreographer﹕ Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Whenever you see this, think that the problem is that you are doing much work in the UI thread (you should use Handler/Asynctask/Thread) or like in this case you have an infinite loop.